# How To Install ADOCE In a Jornada 720(HPC 2000)

Tags: database, installation, windows-ce, evb

Someone knows how to install ADOCE in a HP Jornada 720, that uses HPC 2000, please i have to develop an aplication for my company, and i have to use ADOCE in my Jornada 720, remember that  i've tested the application and i've got an error that says that my Handheld didn't have the ActiveX to run that program. Sorry about my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow - it's been nearly a decade since I use a 720, but as I recall, ADOCE is part of the eMbedded Visual Basic 3.0 install package.  Microsoft deprecated that yeas ago and even pulled support completely (it's not even in MSDN).  You now have to download it from sites that have archived it [like this one](http://embedded-visual-tools.en.softonic.com/pocketpc).

All that said, I serious question why your company would spend a dollar or a minute working on new development for a device like that or with those tools.  IMO it's an absolute waste of effort.  It certainly can't be maintained, extended or scaled.